# How to apply ball tree to pandas df column

Tags: python, pandas, cluster-analysis

I'm applying the ball tree clustering algorithm to my pandas df column `sp500news3['phrase_vector']` (sample below)

I've already tried

```
from  sklearn.neighbors import BallTree
import numpy as np

tree = BallTree(sp500news3['phrase_vector'])     
print(tree.query_radius(sp500news3['phrase_vector'][:1], r=0.3, count_only=True))

ind = tree.query_radius(sp500news3['phrase_vector'][:1], r=0.3)  
print(ind)  # indices of neighbors within distance 0.
```

which returns `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.` pointing to this line `tree = BallTree(sp500news3['phrase_vector'])`

```
sp500news3['phrase_vector']
0       [-1.464906, 1.6889418, -1.750461, 0.54739094, ...
1       [-1.2658471, 1.250561, 0.59811795, -4.5680103,...
2       [-2.5886421, 3.0229673, -1.7595533, -3.804605,...
3       [-1.9567089, 3.6295261, 0.44644845, -2.5851138...
4       [-0.8531435, 1.686829, -2.1624348, -2.82526, 0...
```

Comment: what happens if you do `tree = BallTree(sp500news3['phrase_vector'].values`)

Comment: returns the same error

Comment: wait, phrase_vector is a list of lists/arrays?

Comment: Have removed extra list -  each item in `sp500news3['phrase_vector']` is now simply an array (See sample). Same error

Comment: yeah, that's not the format expected by BallTree. You need to provide an array, not a series. Can you share the current contents of phrase_vector?

Comment: it's a large file, each array is 300d and there are ~7k rows

Comment: just the first 5, like you have on your post. If it's a series of arrays then it won't work. You need to make sure you provide an array with the right structure, i.e. and object with 7k rows and 300 columns